# Errors after Meteor upgrade

Tags: meteor

I've just performed `meteor update` which took me to v1.5. I'm getting a lot of `TypeError: module.exportDefault is not a function` errors.
Currently it's at
`at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.react-meteor-data.ReactMeteorData.jsx (packages/react-meteor-data/ReactMeteorData.jsx:1:8)` 
but it happens on several packages. I think it's do with dynamic imports but I can't get to the bottom of it.
Pulling my hair out.

Comment: Can you try out to only update the ecmascript package? `meteor update ecmascript`. Maybe you have the same [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8755).

Answer (score 1):

Meteor is guided by a version configuration file to keep track all of package dependencies of your application. When there an upgrade for a more higher version of Meteor, like version 1.4 for a version 1.5, I always do a version redefinition of all the dependencies of my packages. This avoids problems like this (TypeError: module.exportDefault is not a function). I suggest you do that too.

```
$ cd /your-project-folder
$ meteor reset
$ rm .meteor/versions
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ meteor update --all-packages
$ meteor npm install
$ meteor [--settings settings.json]
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a mess. Had to roll back and go forward again. And by this time a couple dependencies had been updated. Moral, always keep your backups in order.

I did notice that dynamic-import had possibly clagged during install noting the lack of version number. Also, I removed some old blaze stuff and refreshed the npm packages. I'm not entirely sure what solved it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem because modules@0.10.0-pre.1 was installed.
Try to set the version of the modules package to 0.9.1.

1) Install `meteor add modules@0.9.1`
2) Remove `versions` file or set modules version to 0.9.1.